# DojoX slider not working on iOS 8 / safari 8

Tags: dojo, slider, ios8

I had a project in Dojo, with Slider from DojoX. On iPad iOS 6 it was working ok. Now I updated the iPad to iOS 8 - and the slider does not react to touch anymore.
Online demo of slider (http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/touch/demo.html) is also not working on iOS 8.

Anyone has any experience on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you (and the web site as well) are not using the latest Dojo versions that are required for iOS8 support. Upgrading to the latest release will probabably solve your issue.

Comment: You are right - upgrade to Dojo 10.1 was enough to make slider move again on iOS8. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Questions about dojo usage or possible bug are discussed on the [dojo-interest mailing list](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/mailman/listinfo/dojo-interest). Web interfaces are available from the [Dojo Toolkit Community page](https://dojotoolkit.org/community/). If you’ve filing a bug, see [How to File a Dojo Bug Report](http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/how-file-dojo-bug-report)